# In my form for edit users the field name appears but the phone dont ( phone has a jQuery mask)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this basic form for edit users, and Im showing the name and the phone in my inputs.
The name is working fine, but my phone its not appearing.

The only difference, and probably the difference that is ruining everything, is that Im using in my phone input the id="ph" that corresponds to a mask that I am using through jquery **like this:**

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999 99:99:99");
   $("#ph").mask("(99) 9999999");
});
```

Someone there knows how I can solve this problem? Maybe something like strip_tags() but for jQuery, but I dont find nothing about this!

**My Basic form:**

```
 <form name="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Name:</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $resultReadUserEdit['name'] ; ?>" />
        </label>


        <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Phone number:</span>
            <input type="text" id="ph" name="phone" value=" <?php echo $resultReadUserEdit['phone'] ; ?> " />
        </label>

          <input type="submit" value="Edit user" name="sendForm" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see the field when you examine the DOM in Developer Tools?

Comment: Yes, with this value=" (31) (3143 ". Its a strange value because when i create this user I also use the mask, so I put more digits..

Comment: Check the CSS to see if it's being hidden for some reason.

Comment: Do you mean that you're not seeing the initial value, or you're not seeing the input field at all?

Comment: If you're not seeing the value, maybe it's because it doesn't match the mask. You have an extra `(` before the second number. Also, you're putting a space before and after the phone number in your PHP, take that out.

Comment: I was reading better the documentation of my jQuery script and I think its because of the mask script. They say to use like this:  $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999"); But I dont want so many digits and then they just say if I can customize my owns mask like this: jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
   $("#eyescript").mask("~9.99 ~9.99 999");
}); But they dont explain this!!

Comment: Yes, it was because of the mask, I see in other site and with $("#ph").mask("99-9999999"); it works! Thanks for your help! And the plugin im using is MASKED INPUT PLUGIN.

Comment: You can make the mask anything you want, but the value has to match the mask.

Comment: So if you want to allow `(31) (3143` then the mask should be `(99) (9999`.